# google places location and radius search for address do not limit results within radius

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm building an application where i use the google place autocomplete API.
Once user selects a city, I want to limit the addresses results to within that city.

calling the API with this http request:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=dvor&types=address&location=32.716221,35.127483&rankby=distance&radius=2000&key=MY_KEY(replaced).

i get results far beyond the radius provided, even 10sKM away.

anyway to solve this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: There are a couple of issues in your request: 1. when you use `rankby=distance` the radius parameter is not taken into account, so you should remove rankby. 2. you can use `strictbounds` parameters to get results only from specified area: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#location_restrict

Answer (score 0):

Update - found it is working by adding &strictbounds.